# Configuaración de cabeceras en email recibido

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario que envio por email. Bien aquí esta el código del archivo que recibe los datos del formulario:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$request = $_POST['request'];

$to = "webmaster@jsssssss.org";
$subject = "Formulario de contacto";
$headers = "De: $name" . "\r\n" .
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
$message = "$request";

mail ($to,$subject,$headers);
//echo "$name";
//echo "<p></p>";
//echo "$email";
//echo "<p></p>";
//echo "$request";
//echo "<p></p>"; 
echo "Mensaje enviado <a href='index.php'> click aqui</a> para enviar un nuevo mensaje";
?>
```

El caso que recibo bien todos los datos pero lo que quiero es que no me muestre las cabeceras del servidor, que me aparece lo siguiente:
From net1fotov@host.cpseo4.eu on 2021-04-14 11:27
Lo que quiero que aparezca es el email del usuario que lo envia y asi tambien para cuando tenga que responder automaticamente me salga el correo del usuario que me lo ha envidado.
¿No se si podríais echarme una mano?
Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Esto se hace pasando a `mail()` un **cuarto parámetro** que son las cabeceras adicionales (al final puedes leer todo lo que dice el Manual sobre este particula, especialmente con respecto a la **seguridad** y a la configuración).

El problema es que tú estás pasando las cabeceras como tercer parámetro (ese parámetro es para el cuerpo del mensaje). Convendría que rectifiques, pasándolas en cuarto parámetro y completándolas. Puedes agregar el `Reply-To` así como el tipo de contenido, que parece ser html. También estás usando `De:` y deberías usar `From:` (en inglés).

Convendría también que filtres los datos del POST, pues puede ocurrir inyección de cabeceras si lo pasas así. No me he metido con eso, porque es un tema muy amplio, pero deberías considerarlo o bien usar una librería más avanzada como [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

El código debería funcionar así (he dado un nombre más descriptivo a las variables para no hacerse lío con ellas):

```
<?php
    #Convendría sanear las variables del POST
    $fromName = $_POST['name'];
    $fromMail = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['request']; #define como $message directamente
    
    $toName="Webmaster";
    $toMail = "webmaster@jsssssss.org";
    $subject = "Formulario de contacto";


    // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

    // Cabeceras adicionales
    $headers .= "From: $fromName <$fromMail>\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: $toName <$toMail>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $fromMail\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();    

    if ( mail ($toMail,$subject, $message, $headers) ) {
        //echo "$name";
        //echo "<p></p>";
        //echo "$email";
        //echo "<p></p>";
        //echo "$request";
        //echo "<p></p>"; 
        echo "Mensaje enviado <a href='index.php'> click aqui</a> para enviar un nuevo mensaje";
      } else {
        echo "Error enviando el email";
      }
?>
```

---

Te pongo aquí todo lo que dice el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) sobre las cabeceras adicionales, hay aspectos importantes a tener en cuenta, sobre todo con respecto a la seguridad y a la configuración. Si aún usando cabeceras adicionales no funciona, podría deberse a que en `php.ini` haya otro tipo de configuración es que prioritaria y deberías revisar allí.

#### [additional_headers (opcional)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php)

> String a insertar al final de la cabecera del correo.
>
> Se usa normalmente para añadir cabeceras extra (`From`, `Cc` y `Bcc`).
> Las cabeceras múltiples adicionales deberían separarse con un
> CRLF(\r\n). Si se usan datos externos para componer esta cabecera, los
> datos deberían ser saneados para que no se inyecten cabeceras no
> deseadas.
>
> **Nota:**
>
> `additional_headers` no posee protección de inyección de cabeceras de
> correo. Por tanto, los usuarios deben asegurarse de que las cabeceras
> especificadas son seguras y contienen solamente cabeceras. Es decir,
> nunca iniciar el cuerpo del correo con varias nuevas líneas.
>
> **Nota:**
>
> Cuando se envía un correo, este debe contener una cabecera `From`.
> Puede establecerse con el parámetro additional_headers, o puede
> definirse un valor predeterminaro en `php.ini`.
>
> Si no se realiza esta acción se obtendrá un mensaje de error similar a
> *Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing (Advertencia: mail(): "sendmail_from" no establecido en
> php.ini o falta la cabecera personalizada "From:")*. La cabecera
> `From` también establece Return-Path bajo Windows.

Comment: Funciona bien. Voy a mirar tranquilamente la información que me has indicado. Muchas gracias y un saludo.